# bool(false) Uploading a file

Tags: php, apache, file, upload

I have had problems with a simple php script in which I can upload a file to a certain folder. I have tried multiple ways in doing this and I still have not had success.

Any errors in my code or advice on how to correct the issue will be taken gracefully.

Main Php Code:

```
<p>Browse For a File on your computer to upload it!</p>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_photos.php" method="POST">
Choose Photo:
<input name="userfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload Photo" />


<?PHP      


if ($userfile_size>250000)
    {$msg=$msg."Your uploaded file size is more than 250KB so please reduce the file size  and then upload.<BR>";
$file_upload="false";} 

else{

if (!($userfile_type<>"image/jpeg" OR $userfile_type<>"image/tiff" OR     $userfile_type<>"image/png"))
    {$msg=$msg."Your uploaded file must be of JPG, PNG, or tiff. Other file types are not     allowed<BR>";  
$file_upload="false";}

}
  ?>

</form>

</label>
</form>
```

Php code that is called upon on click (upload_photos.php)

```
<?php
$target_path="uploads/";

chmod("uploads/", 0755);
$target_path=$target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

$test=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path); 

 if($test) { 
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).  
    " has been uploaded"; 
 } else{ 
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"; 
    var_dump($test); 
 } 
?>
```

I do not understand why my end results [upon clicking "Upload Files" Button] include only the following results:

"There was an error uploading the file, please try again!bool(false)"

One more thing: I have also tried using the full computer folder path for $target_path and chmod.

Does anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Who owns the `uploads` directory? If it's not `apache` (or whatever user the server is running under) this probably won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `<input name="userfile"` but then use `$_FILES['uploadedfile']` in your script - use one or the other.

Other than that, make sure the `chmod` worked and the folder is writable.

Comment: Joe, thank you so much man. I have been searching for many answers to this issue. I truly appreciate your help and the problem has been solved. You are a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

`bool(false)` is the output of `var_dump($test);`, indicating that [`move_uploaded_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) is returning false.

As a basic debugging step, you should try `var_dump($_FILES)` to make sure you're accessing the right element of that array (I can tell from your code that you aren't, the index will be the `name` attribute of your `<input type="file"/>` element).

You have at least one other serious flaw in your logic... The PHP code in your upload form doesn't make any sense. That block of PHP code will execute server-side before the user has ever uploaded a file. It can't possibly work. The two variables you're checking, `$userfile_size` and `$userfile_type`, are not defined anywhere.

Comment: Yea, i forgot to take those 2 variables out, that's something that I'm playing around with right now (file restrictions and such).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to create a folder where I want to upload. So check once the specified upload path is available or not.